# It does not fit XY image in tablet 7 inch

Tags: android

In my app I fit an image by `android:scaleType="fitXY"` but in a 7 inch tablet it does not fit.

In Nexus One 3.7inch:

[image]

In Nexus 7 7.27inch:

[image]

### XML

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/matn" />

</FrameLayout>
```

What is the problem? Why it doesn't fit?

Comment: Is your Image a LayerDrawable?

Comment: And shouldn't FrameLayout params be match_parent? And why FrameLayout if there's only one View in it?

Comment: Always keep on mind that if you want to match more screen you should use: "match_parent", also remember to use dp instead of px and if you want static position create different resources for different screen using dp. But the most important thing is the use of match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your `FrameLayout` width and height are set to `wrap_content` and in that case if the image is not big enough for the screen then it won't fill it up.

I suggest trying `fill_parent` for your `FrameLayout`.